# PHP -- Closing end DIV tag

Tags: php, html

I need to figure the closing tag for below code

```
<div class="emph"><div class="level"> Some testing </div></div>
```

In this i need to find the correct tag for parent DIV. my goal is to add the class name before the closing DIV like below

```
<div class="emph"><div class="level"> Some testing <!--level--></div><!--emph--></div>
```

For that i need to find the exact closing Parent DIV.

is that possible to achieve in PHP?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Comments should help annotate the source rather than the output that is rendered to the browser.

Comment: Guys, That is my requirement. We are doing some processing once we are able to achieve it. So all i want is find the exact closing div. here i just added the comment one for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simpleXML (or any other XML class) - for each div element, read it's class and append  at the end of node content. It's not exactly finding the closing tag, but achieves your specified goal.

Sample code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$divs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div');
foreach ($divs as $div) {
    if ($div->getAttribute('class')!='') {
        $div->nodeValue = $div->nodeValue.'<!--'.$div->getAttribute('class').'-->';
    }
}
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Comment: well thanks for your quick response . But i'm unable to obtain the goal like this <div class="emph"><div class="level"> Some testing <!--level--></div><!--emph--></div>

Comment: what is the exact problem? Of course apart from the fact, that it expects valid XML.

Answer (score 0):

While printing the `divs` in PHP keep an array `$div_array = array()`
As soon as you open a div do:

```
array_push($div_array, 'emph'); // or 'level' depending on the classname
```

As soon as you're ready to print the closing tag, ask for the value of the last div by:

```
array_pop($div_array);

// for example
echo '<!-- '.array_pop($div_array).' -->';
```

Popping the array also deletes the last entry of the array. Which is what you want I presume.

Comment: buddy, thanks for your response.. can you tell me how to print?.. i dont get the point here..

Comment: Maybe `echo`-ing is a more appropriate way to put it, instead of `print`.